# Spring AOP pointcut expression / including methods of parent class

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am using expresssions like the following in my Spring configuration file:

```
<aop:pointcut expression="within(my.app.dao.impl.*)" id="commonDaoOperation"/>
or
<aop:pointcut expression=" execution(public * my.app.dao.impl.*.*(..))" id="commonDaoOperation"/>
```

The classes I am trying to match (DAOs in that case) extend a common class which is in another package.

Are the pointcut expressions above also supposed to match the methods of the parent class of my classes ?

Or do I need to add expressly the parent class in the expression to have its methods matched:

```
|| within(my.app.dao.common.MyParentClass)
```

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more investigation, I can confirm that the **parent class must be added** to the pointcut expression (unless the parent methods are overriden in the children classes):

`<aop:pointcut expression="within(my.app.dao.impl.*) || within(my.app.dao.common.MyParentClass)" id="commonDaoOperation"/>`